# Google analytics showing weird /browse.php accessed pages

Tags: google-analytics, 404, traffic

In Google Analytics, I'm seeing access to pages that don't exist with weird query params:
Screenshot:
[image]

I don't even have a `browse.php` page. What can this be?

Comment: Somewhere there's probably a link to it. Maybe it used to exist even?

Comment: @Ryan Never existed. Google search for site:mydomain.com/browse.php comes up empty also

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some kind of torrent related scanning script. If your site is using a custom 404 page like the one used by Wordpress and many other CMS's than any wrong address would produce a 404 "valid" analytics page. i can type example.com/adsfsd and it would show up in analytics. Sort your pages in analytics by page title and see if they include the title of the 404 page. I would also check WMT to see if these pages appear there as well and if they do - remove them.

Comment: What tells you this looks like 'torrent related'? How can I check in WMT if they appear?